# I wonder why Blend for Windows 8 removed "make into user control" feature

Tags: windows-8, blend

I love custom user control, has been using it them since Blend 2, I wonder why now we can't select a grid and make into user control anymore in Windows 8? 
We have to add a new item then manually add all the grid into the newly created user control. Any idea behind this? Is that a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, Blend for Silverlight 5 is still a buggy beta, so be happy to have a Blend version for winRT app ^_^#, i love xaml & blend but i'm sure that you will have to wait a loong time before getting and update.

Comment: Have a try to the latest blend version, included in the VS2012 update 2.